# Output 2 Values One Line In For Loop - C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a For loop in a function as follows:

```
int fnSearch(int arnSalaries [10][2], int nSalary, char cFound)
{
    int nRow, nCol;

    printf("Please enter the Salary to find the Employee ID : ");
    scanf("%d", &nSalary);

    for(nRow = 0; nRow < 10; nRow++)
    {
        if(nSalary == arnSalaries[nRow][1])
        {
            printf("\%d found - Employee ID matching that salary is: %d\n", 
                nSalary, arnSalaries[nRow][0]);
            cFound = 'Y';
            //nRow = 10; /* This is to break out of the loop */
        }
    }

    if(cFound == 'N')
    {
        printf("Sorry, that salary does not match an employee\n");
    }

    return cFound;
}
```

When i type in a salary such as "10000", the output is as follows:

```
10000 found - Employee ID matching that salary is: 21
10000 found - Employee ID matching that salary is: 23
```

How can i change the code so it displays something like the following:

```
10000 found - Employee ID(s) matching that salary is/are: 21, 23
```

EDIT:
I am not looking for any code to be written - just a hint in the right direction as to what i should be looking at to solve this issue

Comment: There are several ways. Have you tried to work this out yourself? That's what's preferred at SO, with a question reserved for if you hit a brick wall.

Comment: Save off the matching results in another array in the loop, then print those values out after the loop terminates.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - im new to C - only started very recently so im not very advanced with this kind of thing!

Comment: Thanks OldProgrammer - ill take a bash at that!

Comment: `"Sorry, that..."`  Your code is so polite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Print everything except the id numbers before the loop.
inside the loop, print only the id numbers.
after the loop, print a newline.

Comment: Ah! That is actually a nice out of the box thinking! cheers Chris!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may help you :

```
int fnSearch(int arnSalaries [10][2], int nSalary, char cFound)
{
int nRow, nCol, i = 0;
int foundIndex[] = int[10]; //10 or number of rows of arnSalaries
printf("Please enter the Salary to find the Employee ID : ");
scanf("%d", &nSalary);

for(nRow = 0; nRow < 10; nRow++)
{
    if(nSalary == arnSalaries[nRow][1])
    {
        cFound = 'Y';
        foundIndex[i++] = nRow;
    }
}

if(cFound == 'N')
    printf("Sorry, that salary does not match an employee\n");
else
{
    printf("\%d found - Employee ID matching that salary is/are :",nSalary);
    for(i = 0;i<sizeof(foundIndex);i++)
        printf("%d,",arnSalaries[foundIndex[i]][0])
}

return cFound;
}
```

pls correct some syntax mistakes if there.